# How to add event to google calendar in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-calendar

Currently, I am using [react-native-add-calendar-event](https://github.com/vonovak/react-native-add-calendar-event) package which is doing the job decently.

But it only opens apple calendar in iOS and Google calendar in android, I want to show the list of available calendar apps and want the user to select any one of them and add the event to the selected calendar.

is it even possible?